# PHP file writing optimization

Tags: php, optimization, file, pcre

### EDIT: Optimization results at end of this question!

hi, i have a following code to first scan files in a specific folder and then read every file line by line and after numerous "if...else if" write new modified file to another folder with the name name as it was when opened.

The **problem** is that writing a file line by line seems to be awfully slooooow. The default 60 seconds limit will only be enough for 25, or so, files. File sizes vary from 10k to 350k.

Any way to optimize code to make it running faster. Is it better to read line by lines, put every lines into an array and then write that whole array into a new text file (vs. line by line reading/writing). If it is, how it is done in practice.

thanks in advance
----- The code follows -----

```
<?php

function scandir_recursive($path)    {
...
...
}



$fileselection = scandir_recursive('HH_new');
foreach ($fileselection as $extractedArray) {
$tableName = basename($extractedArray); // Table name
$fileLines=file($extractedArray);
    foreach ($fileLines as $line) {
            if(preg_match('/\(all-in\)/i' , $line)) {
                $line = stristr($line, ' (all-in)', true) .', and is all in';
                $allin = ', and is all in';
            }
            else {
                $allin = '';
            }
            if(preg_match('/posts the small blind of \$[\d\.]+/i' , $line)) {
                $player = stristr($line, ' posts ', true);
                $betValue = substr(stristr($line, '$'), 1);
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
            }
            else if(preg_match('/posts the big blind of \$[\d\.]+/i' , $line)) {
                $player = stristr($line, ' posts ', true);
                $betValue = substr(stristr($line, '$'), 1);
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
            }
            else if(preg_match('/\S+ raises /i' , $line)) {
                $player = stristr($line, ' raises ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue; //total bet this hand (shortcut)
            }
            else if(preg_match('/\S+ bets /i' , $line)) {
                $player = stristr($line, ' bets ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue; //total bet this hand (shortcut)
            }
            else if(preg_match('/\S+ calls /i' , $line)) {
                $player = stristr($line, ' calls ', true);
                $betValue = substr(stristr($line, '$'), 1);
                $callValue = $betValue - $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal']; //actual amount called
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
                $line = stristr($line, '$', true)."\$".$callValue.$allin;
                $allin = '';
            }
            else if(preg_match('/(\*\*\* (Flop|Turn|River))|(Full Tilt Poker)/i' , $line)) {
                unset($bettingMatrix); //zero $betValue
            }
            else if(preg_match('/\*\*\* FLOP \*\*\*/i' , $line)) {
                $flop = substr(stristr($line, '['), 0, -2);
                $line = '*** FLOP *** '. $flop;
            }
            else if(preg_match('/\*\*\* TURN \*\*\*/i' , $line)) {
                $turn = substr(stristr($line, '['), 0, -2);
                $line = '*** TURN *** '. $flop .' '. $turn;
            }
            else if(preg_match('/\*\*\* RIVER \*\*\*/i' , $line)) {
                $river = substr(stristr($line, '['), 0, -2);
                $line = '*** RIVER *** '. substr($flop, 0, -1) .' '. substr($turn, 1) .' '. $river;
            }
            else {
            }
        $ourFileHandle = fopen("HH_newest/".$tableName.".txt", 'a') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($ourFileHandle, $line);
        fclose($ourFileHandle);
    }
}
?>
```

---

EDIT:
Here's VERY interesting results after rewriting the code based on tips everyone here gave me.

60 text files, 5.8MB total

After all optimization (changed preg->strpos/strstr & $handle before loop): **4 sec.**

As above BUT changed strpos/strstr -> stripos/stristr: **8 sec.**

As above BUT changed stripos/stristr -> preg: **12 sec.**

As above BUT changed fopen inside the loop: **45/60 files after 180sec run limit**

Here's the complete script:

```
$fileselection = scandir_recursive('HH_new');
foreach ($fileselection as $extractedArray) {
    $tableName = basename($extractedArray); // Table name
    $handle         = fopen($extractedArray, 'r');
    $ourFileHandle  = fopen("HH_newest/".$tableName.".txt", 'a') or die("can't open file");
    while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
            if (FALSE !== strpos($line, '(all-in)')) {
                $line = strstr($line, ' (all-in)', true) .", and is all in\r\n";
                $allin = ', and is all in';
            } else {
                $allin = '';
            }
            if (FALSE !== strpos($line, ' posts the small blind of $')) {
                $player = strstr($line, ' posts ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, ' posts the big blind of $')) {
                $player = strstr($line, ' posts ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, ' posts $')) {
                $player = strstr($line, ' posts ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] += $betValue;
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, ' raises to $')) {
                $player = strstr($line, ' raises ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $betMade = $betValue - $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal']; //actual amount raised by
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue; //$line contains total bet this hand (shortcut)
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, ' bets $')) {
                $player = strstr($line, ' bets ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $betMade = $betValue - $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal']; //actual amount raised by
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue; //$line contains total bet this hand (shortcut)
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, ' calls $')) {
                $player = strstr($line, ' calls ', true);
                $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
                $callValue = $betValue - $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal']; //actual amount called
                $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
                $line = strstr($line, '$', true)."\$".$callValue.$allin. "\r\n";
                $allin = '';
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, '*** FLOP ***')) {
                $flop = substr(strstr($line, '['), 0, -2);
                unset($bettingMatrix); //zero $betValue
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, '*** TURN ***')) {
                $turn = substr(strstr($line, '['), 0, -2);
                $line = '*** TURN *** '.$flop.' '.$turn."\r\n";
                unset($bettingMatrix); //zero $betValue
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, '*** RIVER ***')) {
                $river = substr(strstr($line, '['), 0, -2);
                $line = '*** RIVER *** '. substr($flop, 0, -1) .' '. substr($turn, 1) .' '. $river."\r\n";
                unset($bettingMatrix); //zero $betValue
            }
            else if (FALSE !== strpos($line, 'Full Tilt Poker')) {
                unset($bettingMatrix); //zero $betValue
            }
            else {
            }
        fwrite($ourFileHandle, $line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the performance gain of non-regex matching against the gain of less file I/O.

Comment: i will post some results when get back to "my lab".

Comment: my code here is based on MalphasWats's code. The original, very confusing, question of mine could be found from link below. If you will look at it, only the call value needs to be worked.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665927/php-regex-and-compare-variables-in-a-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think this is because you're opening/closing file within the loop, try moving fopen() before foreach and fclose after it

Comment: then it will only write the last line of each file into a new files, won't it?

Comment: I agree that you definitely don't want to be doing I/O that many times. It might be quicker just to append each modified line to a new string then write out the new string once.

Comment: As long as you leave the fwrite() in the loop, it will just leave the file open and continue to write each line to it.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt the file writing is the performance issue here. You're running **ten** regular expressions on *everything*!

Using string methods like [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the sub-strings might speed things up.

Comment: how do i replace my "preg_match('/\S+ calls /i' , $line)" with strpos()? Is there a subsitute for "\S+"?

Comment: It's only 10 if none of the first 9 match.  Given that, re-aranging the if-elseifs to test in order of probability would likely imporove performance somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Doing away with the regular expression would give you the most performance increase, if you can change them to [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or similar - stripos() for case insensitive - you should notice a speed increase.

The test needs to be `'!== false'`, since the found string may be at position 0. For example, your first test case could be ():

```
if(stripos($line, '(all-in)') !== false) {
    //generate output
}
```

You also may find using fgets() instead of reading the whole file at one time may give you some performance increase (but that's more a memory issue). And as mentioned by others, only write to the file in the loop, don't open and close it.

Comment: i've been wondering why it has to be "is not false" instead of just "true"? Does it give better performance or reliability?

Comment: @mika - The PHP manual page for strpos() prominently explains that.

Comment: @minka I added short explanation, and linked the function name to manual page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code with a few tiny changes that should help quite a bit

1. Switched from `file()` to `fgets()`.  This will load only a single line at a time into memory instead of every line from the file.
2. Changed your calls to `preg_match()` to `stripos()` where applicable. Should be a tiny bit faster
3. Moved the opening/closing of `$ourFileHandle` into the outer loop.  This will *significantly* reduce the number of stat calls to the filesystem and should speed it up greatly.

There are probably a lot of other optimizations that can be made in that monstrous if..else but i'll leave those up to another SOer (or you)

```
$fileselection = scandir_recursive('HH_new');
foreach ($fileselection as $extractedArray)
{ 
  $tableName     = basename( $extractedArray ); // Table name
  $handle        = fopen( $extractedArray, 'r' );
  $ourFileHandle = fopen("HH_newest/".$tableName.".txt", 'a') or die("can't open file");

  while ( $line = fgets( $handle ) )
  {
    if ( false !== stripos( $line, '(all-in)' ) )
    {
      $line = stristr($line, ' (all-in)', true) .', and is all in';
      $allin = ', and is all in';
    } else {
      $allin = '';
    }
    if ( preg_match('/posts the small blind of \$[\d\.]+/i' , $line ) )
    {
            $player = stristr($line, ' posts ', true);
            $betValue = substr(stristr($line, '$'), 1);
            $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
    }
    else if(preg_match('/posts the big blind of \$[\d\.]+/i' , $line)) {
            $player = stristr($line, ' posts ', true);
            $betValue = substr(stristr($line, '$'), 1);
            $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
    }
    else if(preg_match('/\S+ raises /i' , $line)) {
            $player = stristr($line, ' raises ', true);
            $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
            $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue; //total bet this hand (shortcut)
    }
    else if(preg_match('/\S+ bets /i' , $line)) {
            $player = stristr($line, ' bets ', true);
            $betValue = substr(strstr($line, '$'), 1);
            $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue; //total bet this hand (shortcut)
    }
    else if(preg_match('/\S+ calls /i' , $line)) {
            $player = stristr($line, ' calls ', true);
            $betValue = substr(stristr($line, '$'), 1);
            $callValue = $betValue - $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal']; //actual amount called
            $bettingMatrix[$player]['betTotal'] = $betValue;
            $line = stristr($line, '$', true)."\$".$callValue.$allin;
            $allin = '';
    }
    else if(preg_match('/(\*\*\* (Flop|Turn|River))|(Full Tilt Poker)/i' , $line)) {
            unset($bettingMatrix); //zero $betValue
    }
    else if ( FALSE !== stripos( $line, '*** FLOP ***' ) )
    {
            $flop = substr(stristr($line, '['), 0, -2);
            $line = '*** FLOP *** '. $flop;
    }
    else if ( FALSE !== stripos( $line, '*** TURN ***' ) )
    {
            $turn = substr(stristr($line, '['), 0, -2);
            $line = '*** TURN *** '. $flop .' '. $turn;
    }
    else if ( FALSE !== stripos( $line, '*** RIVER ***' ) )
    {
            $river = substr(stristr($line, '['), 0, -2);
            $line = '*** RIVER *** '. substr($flop, 0, -1) .' '. substr($turn, 1) .' '. $river;
    }
    else {
    }
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, $line);
  }
  fclose( $handle );
  fclose( $ourFileHandle );
}
```

Comment: thanks.. i will rewrite my code based on your code here and keep in my the other ideas everybody has told here.